# Installing Docker on Windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10, wsl-2

I want to install Docker on my Windows computer and I am doing this following this documentation: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/. When I come to step 3 I cannot see the option **Use WSL 2 instead of Hyper-V** to check it. Why?

[image: Docker Desktop]

I installed it completely but when I run it, it stuck at the step starting the engine and I actually cannot go to setting of Docker.

I think I have to mention I installed WSL 2 and Ubuntu on my Windows computer successfully.

Comment: Could you just use `apt` in WSL to install Docker on the command line?

Comment: @halfer Thank you very much for your suggestion. I will search more about it and try it.

Comment: I should think it would just be `sudo apt install -y docker.io`, assuming you're OK with Docker working just on the console.